# Cell in table wont color on click (CodeNewbie)

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to create a pixel generator, I think it is almost there but when I click the cells in the table they do not change color to the selected color that was chosen.  Please can you help?

I tried to add the following in JavaScript but it did not work:

```
table.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === "td") {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = colorGrid;
  }
}
```

I also added to the above suggested code by stating the table as a variable as I thought the table variable declared already may have been constrained to local scope, but that also did not work.

Thanks

```js
// Select color input
var colorGrid = document.getElementById("colorPicker");

// Select size input
var sizeHeight = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
var sizeWidth = document.getElementById("inputWidth").value;

// When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()
const form = document.getElementById("sizePicker");
form.addEventListener("submit", makeGrid);

function makeGrid(event) {
  // stop automatic reset of form
  event.preventDefault();
  // body reference - get first <body></body>
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

  // Your code goes here!
  var table = document.getElementById("pixelCanvas");
  var tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  // cells creation
  for (let i = 1; i <= sizeHeight; i++) {
    // create table row
    var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");

    for (let i = 1; i <= sizeWidth; i++) {
      // create table cells (cols) within each row - loop within loop
      var tableCell = document.createElement("td");
      // append cell to the row
      tableRow.appendChild(tableCell);
    }

    // add row to the table
    table.appendChild(tableRow);
  }
  // append the table body inside the table
  table.appendChild(tableBody);
}
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Monoton;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (event.target.tagName === "td") {` should be `if (event.target.tagName === "TD") {` Also, `colorGrid` is a reference to the color input element. To get its value you need `colorGrid.value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code that I'll address first.

When the script first loads it's assigning the value of those inputs to a variable. At *that point* the value is an empty string so that won't work properly when you come to the iteration part of the script. You should change

```
var sizeHeight = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
```

to

```
var sizeHeight = document.getElementById("inputHeight");
```

and then get the value when you loop because at that point the inputs will be complete:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= sizeHeight.value; i++) {
```

Second, you create a `tableBody` element but you don't use it - you append the rows directly to the `table` element instead.

Finally, you should probably clear the table's HTML content on each submission so you remove the existing grid before adding a new one.

In terms of how you change the colour of the grid boxes there are a couple of routes you can take. 1) Add a listener to each box which calls a function when it is fired 2) Add [*one* listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the table to catch events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM. This is known as [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) and is what this example uses. When the listener catches an event it checks that the element that fired the event [is a table cell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches), and then adjusts the cell's background colour.

```js
const colorGrid = document.getElementById('colorPicker');

// Just assign the elements to the variables,
// not the values
const sizeHeight = document.getElementById('inputHeight');
const sizeWidth = document.getElementById('inputWidth');

const form = document.getElementById('sizePicker');
form.addEventListener('submit', makeGrid);

function makeGrid(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  const table = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');
  const tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  // Reset the table HTML
  table.innerHTML = '';

  // Add a listener to the table element which calls
  // `handleClick`
  table.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
  
  // `handleClick` checks to see if the element that
  // fired the event is a table cell, and then it
  // sets its background color to the value of your
  // `colorGrid` input
  function handleClick(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('td')) {
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = colorGrid.value;
    }
  }

  // Using the value of `sizeHeight`
  for (let i = 1; i <= sizeHeight.value; i++) {

    const tableRow = document.createElement('tr');

    // Using the value of `sizeWidth`
    for (let i = 1; i <= sizeWidth.value; i++) {
      const tableCell = document.createElement('td');
      tableRow.appendChild(tableCell);
    }

    // Appending to the tableBody element rather than
    // the table element
    tableBody.appendChild(tableRow);
  
  }

  table.appendChild(tableBody);

}
```

```css
body{text-align:center}h1{font-family:Monoton;font-size:70px;margin:.2em}h2{margin:1em 0 .25em}h2:first-of-type{margin-top:.5em}table,td,tr{border:1px solid #000}table{border-collapse:collapse;margin:0 auto}tr{height:20px}td{width:20px}input[type=number]{width:6em}td:hover{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<form id="sizePicker">
  Grid Height:
  <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
  <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<h2>Pick A Color</h2>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker">

<h2>Design Canvas</h2>
<table id="pixelCanvas"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your event listener, you are setting the background color to `colorGrid`, which is actually an element (*input*). You want the value of that input instead.

```
 event.target.style.backgroundColor = colorGrid.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `onclick` before appending the child:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= sizeWidth; i++) {
      // create table cells (cols) within each row - loop within loop
      var tableCell = document.createElement("td");
      
      // add onclick
      tableCell.onclick = (e) => {
        e.target.style.background = colorGrid.value;
      }
      
      // append cell to the row
      tableRow.appendChild(tableCell);
    }
```

---

Updated demo:

```js
// Select color input
var colorGrid = document.getElementById("colorPicker");

// Select size input
var sizeHeight = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
var sizeWidth = document.getElementById("inputWidth").value;

// When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()
const form = document.getElementById("sizePicker");
form.addEventListener("submit", makeGrid);

function makeGrid(event) {
  // stop automatic reset of form
  event.preventDefault();
  // body reference - get first <body></body>
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

  // Your code goes here!
  var table = document.getElementById("pixelCanvas");
  var tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");


  // cells creation
  for (let i = 1; i <= sizeHeight; i++) {
    // create table row
    var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");

    for (let i = 1; i <= sizeWidth; i++) {
      // create table cells (cols) within each row - loop within loop
      var tableCell = document.createElement("td");
      
      // add onclick
      tableCell.onclick = (e) => {
        e.target.style.background = colorGrid.value;
      }
      
      // append cell to the row
      tableRow.appendChild(tableCell);
    }

    // add row to the table
    table.appendChild(tableRow);
  }
  // append the table body inside the table
  table.appendChild(tableBody);
}
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Monoton;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There was an issue in the original code that your answer doesn't address if you run your snippet.